# DLLNotFound when using DLLImport with shared library

Tags: c++, .net, linux, shared-libraries, wine

I am creating a .NET Framework 4.0 application that use a DLL when launch on Windows and a shared library wrote in C++ when launch on Linux (debian version 10).

The C# codes looks like that :

```cs
[DllImport("graf")]
private static extern int Method1();
```

On Windows, everything is fine, and the application works very well.
On Linux, I use Wine to start the application. The problem is that when i try to use any method from my library, I got a `DLLNotFoundException: graf`.

My shared library is in `/lib`, `/usr/lib` and in the exe folder. I tried with renaming my libraries `libgraf.so` and only `graf.dll` but it's not working.

I followed every step of this [link](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/pinvoke/). But I can't use my .so library.

Do you have any clue to fix that ?

EDIT: Ok it's seems to be a problem in my shared library compilation.

Comment: Have you read the documentation yet? [Writing cross platform P/Invoke code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/native-interop/cross-platform)

Comment: Yes, but it's not much different from the link I read about. The problem remains the same, the .so library is not found by the program. Do you think that it can come from Wine (or mono)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem came from the fact that 1) my library was badly compiled (Makefile problem); and 2) I had to use the keyword `extern "C" {` in the definitions of my functions.

See [What is the effect of extern "C" in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041866/) for more details.